# unit testing custom directive

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

**I'm using material angular and I have a form with mat-checkbox.**

Above the checkbox there are terms of use and user must scroll the terms of use to bottom for enable the mat-checkbox which is disabled by default.

The problem is that using [disabled] directive send a message (it's not good to use directive must use in ts blablabla).

My solution is to create dedicated directive:

```
export class MyDisabledDirective {
 @Input() set myDisabled(condition: boolean) {
    const input = this.ngControl.control;
    condition ? input.disable() : input.enable();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl: NgControl ) {
  }
}
```

Ok very simple, it works.

Now I need to do unit test for this directive but it's like impossible, anything I try doesn't work.

Right now the specs look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: fake-component',
  template: `
    <button [myDisabled]="condition">Testing</button>
  `,
})
class FakeComponent {
  condition = true;
}

describe('DisabledDirective', () => {
  let component: FakeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FakeComponent>;
  let button: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FakeComponent, MyDisabledDirective],
      providers: [NgControl],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FakeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
  });

  it('should disable if the condition is true', () => {
    component.condition = true;
    expect(button.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should enable if the condition is false', () => {
    component.condition = true;
    expect(button.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

It doesn't work and *button.nativeElement.disabled* is false every time.
And I wonder if the way I'm trying to make the tests is good.

**Hope You can help me, Regards**

console.log:
[image]

Comment: Add fixture.detectChanges() right after you change the condition property.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala I have tryed but I get "'TypeError: Cannot read property 'disable' of undefined'"

Comment: Post your FakeComponent code. HTML and TS

Comment: @AnjilDhamala It's a fake component for testing above my class, exactly like the code I posted lmao

Comment: Oops. I didn't see the component. My bad! It looks like the code is not finding the button. See if you can log button.nativeElement before before expectation. I assume that it is undefined.

Comment: it's not undefined but it's weird it's not object (look edit)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190657/discussion-between-anjil-dhamala-and-msu-arven).